# similar functions like sp.linalg.norm, sp.cross in C++

Tags: python, c++, math

In python we have library *scipy* containing *sp.linalg.norm*, *sp.cross*. Are there any similar functions in C++ *boost* library?

Comment: Search the web for "c++ big number library" and "c++ multiprecision library".

Comment: The GNU Scientific Library might be of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be.

However, OpenCV has what you need!

L2 norm: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm
Cross: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Point_

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    cv::Point3d p1(1, 0, 0);
    cv::Point3d p2(0, 1, 0);

    cv::Point3d cross_prod = p1.cross(p2);

    std::cout 
        << "<" << cross_prod.x 
        << ", " << cross_prod.y 
        << ", " << cross_prod.z 
        << ">"
        << std::endl;

    std::cout << "L2 norm: " << cv::norm(cross_prod) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
<0, 0, 1>
L2 norm: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, It seem correct. It is new account, so I doesn't have enough reputation I cannot vote this answer.

Comment: Hello, ClawMon. could you also help me with this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472133/how-to-create-coordinate-matrix-using-opencv-in-c-like-sp-sparse-coo-matrix-i

Comment: I will have a look at it. In the meantime, can you select this answer as the correct answer? If you do, I will have enough points to comment on your post.